# Condition for a finite sequence of real random variables to be independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The following question is from Tao's blog: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/: Let ${X_1,\dots,X_n}$ be real scalar random variables. Show that ${X_1,\dots,X_n}$ are jointly independent if and only if one has

$\displaystyle {\bf P}( \bigwedge_{i=1}^n (X_i \leq t_i) ) = \prod_{i=1}^n {\bf P}( X_i \leq t_i )$

for all ${t_1,\dots,t_n \in {\bf R}}$.

**Question**: One direction is obvious. Now let $A(S)$ be the property of any Borel subset $S = \prod_{i=1}^n S_i \subset {\bf R}^n$ that ${\bf P}(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n (X_i \in S_i)) = \prod_{i=1}^n {\bf P}(X_i \in S_i)$. As boxes of the form $\prod_{i=1}^n(-\infty, t_i]$ generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on ${\bf R}^n$, a natural thought is to induct on this set of generators. In particular, we need the property $A$ to be closed under countable union to close the induction. That is, if $(S_k)_{k=1}^\infty \subset {\bf R}^n$ is a sequence of Borel subsets such that $A(S_k)$ hold for all $k$, $S_k = \prod_{i=1}^n S_{i,k}$, then $A(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty S_k)$ also holds, but I struggled to express this union as a Cartesian product, against which we can verify $A$. Another difficulty appears in showing that the property $A$ is closed under complementation, namely, $A(S^C)$ holds when $A(S)$ holds, which is also required for the induction to close. Is this a valid approach for the problem after all? Or is there a different approach to the solution?

Comment: Use the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem. It's a rigorous form of "induction".

Comment: @Mason: Since we only covered the monotone class theorem,  and it's basically equivalent to the Dynkin $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, can we use the former instead? Would you provide a bit more explanation on how it works specifically in this case?

Comment: Let $\mu$ denote the law of $X_1, \dots, X_n$ and let $\nu$ denote the product measure. Let $C$ be the collection of Borel sets $A$ for which $\mu(A) = \nu(A)$. It is straightforward to show that $C$ is a monotone class. By assumption, $C$ contains the collection $I$ of all half open intervals in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $I$ generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, if you can show that $C$ contains the algebra generated by $I$, then you are done. This is easy, as  this algebra is the collection of finite disjoint unions of rectangles.

Comment: The reason I suggest $\pi-\lambda$ here is because it is simpler and more natural since you are given a $\pi$-system already.

Comment: @Mason: It's rather straightforward indeed, thanks.